# Fluid css floats

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a fluid element for a site i'm working on, Check out this JS fiddle and make your browser a bit wider, you will see a grey line, a black box, and then a grey line.

When the browser's width is lower the right side line breaks down to the next line, but i want this to stay together no matter how wide the browser is. I generally use float's but have tried a few things, as you can see some css is commented out cause i'm playing with it.

Does anybody have some cool tricks to show me? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need any info.

http://jsfiddle.net/r8Xka/

CSS

```
header .lower{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:95%;
    margin:40px auto 0 auto;
}
header .lower .line{
    /*float:left;*/
    display:inline-block;
    background:#eaebeb;
    width:35%;
    height:8px;
    /*display:block;*/
    position:relative;
    top:18px;
}
header .lower a{
    /*float:left;*/
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 20px;
    /*display:block;*/
    background: #000;
    width: 141px;
    height: 42px;
}
```

HTML

```
<header data-behavior="randomHeader">           
  <div class="lower">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <a href="" title="Play Video" class="btn-play_video" data-behavior="video">Play Video</a>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You've defined a fixed width for your video player, but a variable width for the lines. When the container gets small enough, that is going to want to wrap. You might want to look into [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to detect small screen sizes, and define a different layout for that case.

Comment: Do you want input some content into .line-elements or you need this elements only as "bg-elements"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 column: left - fluid, middle - fixed, right - fluid. You would need some js to make it work.

Or some html/css trick like this:

```
<header data-behavior="randomHeader">           
        <div class="lower">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="center">
                <a href="" title="Play Video" class="btn-play_video" data-behavior="video">Play Video</a>
            </div>          
        </div>
</header>
```

Css:

```
header .lower{
    width:95%;
    margin:40px auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
header .lower .line{
    background:#eaebeb;
    height:8px;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
header .lower a{
    border: 10px solid #FFF;
    display:inline-block;
    background: #000;
    width: 141px;
    height: 42px;
}
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQ8SM/)

Comment: damnit, i really wish i though of this way. So much easyer hah. Thanks dude!